# What happens to the data when updating the app in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm saving data in both IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings and ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder in a windows phone 8 application. If i push an update to the existing application, what will happen to the data available in these locations. Will they still be available ?

Thanks
Kumaran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will still be preserved. The only thing to note is to make sure what users have stored will still work with your code changes. e.g. If you store any xml and json data will it's schema still be right or do you need to write some code to convert it to a newer version.

If you have any data stored in the LINQ to SQL db then any new tables / columns that you've added wont automatically be there. You need to run some extra code to get them created. But sound's like your not going to have that issue anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just need the available data. I am not changing anything regarding the data read/save. Only worried about the existing data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes all the data is preserved.
Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg442301%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Updatingappsandisolatedstorage) to MSDN.

> When you update your app, any data in the isolated storage is
>   preserved. However, data in the isolated storage is deleted if the
>   user uninstalls and then reinstalls your app.